# Always eager load association in CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-4.x

In my CakePHP 4 project, I have two models with a one-to-many relationship between them:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ContentsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('contents');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        // more relations here

        $this->belongsTo('ContentTypes', [
            'className'  => 'ContentTypes',
            'foreignKey' => 'content_type_key',
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ContentTypesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('content_types');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasMany('Contents',[
            'foreignKey' => 'content_type_key',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can assure that the `ContentTypes` table is **always** joined to `Contents`, whenever I query it?

What I would like to achieve is that every time I retrieve a `Content` entity, the corresponding `ContentType` entity is also already available.

I stumbled upon the [EagerLoader](https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/class-Cake.ORM.EagerLoader.html) and [EagerLoadable](https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/class-Cake.ORM.EagerLoadable.html)classes while googling, but couldn't find any examples on how to actually use them.

Comment: See https://github.com/jeremyharris/cakephp-lazyload, either as a package to use, or inspiration for your own code.

Comment: @GregSchmidt lazy loading is exactly the opposite of what I need. If anything, I need "extra-eager" loading. I explicitly want to avoid extra queries every time I access the linked `ContentType` entity, because since I know I'm going to have to access it *very often*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this was way easier than I originally thought.
All I had to do was add a `beforeFind` method to the `ContentsTable` class:

```
    public function beforeFind(EventInterface $event, Query $query)
    {
        $query->contain('ContentTypes');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom finder like:

```
// in your ContentsTable.php
public function findWithType(Query $query, array $options):Query{
   return $query->contain(['ContentTypes']);
}

// somewhere in your application
$contents = $this->Contents->find('withType');
```

So everytime you need your contents you use this finder.